# Save virtual and non-physical files

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, temporary-files, pyglet

Using base64 you can convert a file to a string and then convert the string back into a new image:

```
import base64
with open("first_image.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

fh = open("second_image.png", "wb")
fh.write(base64.b64decode(str))
fh.close()
```

With the script written above, however, a physical "copy" of the image is created. I need instead to have three images (converted already in strings) that are saved as virtual images. This is because these three images are used during the loading of the script and must be separated from the rest. In this way, if the files necessary for the script (such as modules, images and other) are missing, those three images will still be present. In this case the three images are: "logo", "progress bar" and "warnings".

So, how do I save images not as physical files, but as virtual files that can be used as normal files?

EDIT:

I looked around a bit and I managed to create this class for my script:

```
ico_16 = here is the string for the image

pyglet.image.load(__temporary__(ico_16, "ico_16", ".png"))


class __temporary__():
    def __init__(self, str, px, sx):
        self.__ip__ = str
        self.__px__ = px
        self.__sx__ = sx
        self.__temp__()

    def __temp__(self):
        with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=100000, mode="wb", prefix=self.__px__,
                                           suffix=self.__sx__) as __op__:
            __op__.write(base64.b64decode(self.__ip__))
            __op__.seek(0)
        return __op__
```

I'm using Pyglet, but my question is valid for any type of module used in the end. For example, in Pyglet, images are opened with:

```
file = open(filename, 'rb')
```

The problem is that I have to give it a name and not a file, so I do not know how to solve it.

In fact, when I try to start the script, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/Project/PEDPD/main.py", line 153, in <module>
    window = PyEngine()
  File "F:/Python/Project/PEDPD/main.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.__icon_16__ = pyglet.image.load(__temporary__(ico_16, "ico_16", ".png"))
  File "F:\Python\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 180, in load
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
TypeError: invalid file: <__main__.__temporary__ object at 0x00000000159D3128>
```

I tried to open the Tempfile module (since the guide to the module does not give much useful information, at least in my opinion). Unfortunately, in my eyes, I did not notice anything that could help me in any way.

Comment: What do you mean by a virtual file? Do you want to have an in-memory IO-handle?

Comment: In practice, instead of saving the file in the computer's memory, I would like the file to be saved in the virtual memory of the computer. I can not explain well. It seems to me that for example the "StringIo" module saves the strings in virtual memory. I would like to do the same thing, but with the three images.

Comment: Memory is RAM. That's what I've meant by having an in-memory IO-handle. What you mean by memory is usually called storage/disk. Can you show how you are going to use these handles?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Are you simply gonna use them to fake binary IO buffers, i.e. as though a return value from `open("first_image.png", "rb")`.

Comment: Images will be loaded and displayed with pyglet. All this is more to avoid creating temporary files that are created at the beginning, and then be deleted once the script ends. If they are saved on RAM, at least I avoid this step, right?

Comment: I was reading about "tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile", but I did not quite understand how to use it and if it's okay for my purpose

Comment: Your tempfile is destroyed as soon as you leave its context manager, hence the error.

Comment: And you really shouldn't use `__name__`-style names, because they are used to highlight special methods/attributes.

Comment: As for the __name __- style names, I knew that they could be used to show that that type of variables or functions or classes were deprived of the module.

Comment: So does it have to stay in the same class where it is used, or is it also closed by changing function?

Comment: Furthermore, is it also closed when the class is a child of the class that requires it?

Comment: It is closed as soon as you leave the context manager (which is the documented behaviour). All other things do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an in-memory binary IO handle, then `io.BytesIO` is what you seek.

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: with io.BytesIO() as handle:
   ...:     handle.write(b'abc')
   ...:     handle.seek(0)
   ...:     print(next(handle))
   ...:     
b'abc'
```

You can also initialise the handle with some data instead of calling `write` and `seek`

```
In [3]: handle = io.BytesIO(b'abc')

In [4]: next(handle)
Out[4]: b'abc'
```

Comment: in doing so, however, the string remains in my memory, right? On the other hand, I need to remember the images obtained from the strings. I modified the question, in fact, to add more information.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 yes, the strings remain in RAM and are never written to disk. You can write the file to disk yourself, though.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 if you *"need to remember the images obtained from the strings"*, they why do you ask for an in-memory IO storage in the first place?

Comment: I did not ask, but I explained what I was trying to do. I apologize if you misunderstood or if I have misunderstood myself. In practice, I need to save the three images on the RAM and not on the ROM.

Comment: I ask forgiveness for my grammatical errors, but I'm using google translator.

Comment: @BlackFenix06  *"In practice, I need to save the three images on the RAM and not on the ROM"* – then `io.BytesIO` has you covered, though you either shouldn't use the context manager or should do all your calculations in the context.